# How do I filter an object by the child class name in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following classes:

```
class Zoo(models.Model):
    name ...
    address ...
    animal = models.ManyToManyField('Animal', related_name='animals')


class Animal(TypedModel):
    name ...
    description ...

class Tiger(Animal):
    ....

class Lion(Animal):
    ....
```

How can I filter the Lions of the zoo by the class name?? The problem is because sometimes I want to filter only the Zoos with Lions for example...

Note: In my context, I don't know the name or id of the Animal only the model name.

Comment: Are you using django-typed-models?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the django-typed-models the base model Animal contains a type field on which you can filter. 
If you want only lions in the zoo you should do something like:
    zoo.animals.filter(type='myapp.lion')

Comment: Is not working ... 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'